# Hadoop external jars

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hdfs

I am trying to run a hadoop job on a server. The version is `0.20.2`.

I have a big amount of jars, I am running:

```
hadoop jar GenData.jar -libjars /path/jar1,path/jar2,...
```

I am getting the error below even if the corresponding classes are inside the jars:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/avro/mapreduce/AvroKeyInputFormat  at
>   GenerateTrainningData.main(GenerateTrainningData.java:256)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Comment: Check my answer here, I have explained all the available options to fix this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36227260/1766402

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting this exception from Hadoop client side, Mapreduce driver code execution happens in Client JVM. In hadoop -libjars is a generic option which is used for adding dependent jars to mapper/reducer. In your case for adding Jars to Client set you may set the following environment variable,before executing the hadoop command.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=<PATH_to_jar>/Jar1:<PATH_to_jar>/Jar2;
```

(colon ":" can be used for specifying more than 1 jars, In your case you may add the Jar that contains the class `org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat`).

**New edits**

Here first of all you need to find the jar containing the class `org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat`. You can find the class inside the jar `avro-mapred*.jar` (Get the compatible version of `avro-mapred-version.jar` from internet ) include the same in your classpath using the **above command**.

Comment: Having the exact same problem and this did not fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `avro-mapred` dependency.