# ClassNotFoundException when running from local to remote

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have a `mapreduce` code working fine on my local. Then when I run it on a remote server, I get this execption

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getInputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

In my `IntelliJ` ide, I have an external library `avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar`, from which I built the artifacts. When I unzip the `jar` of the artifact, I fiund correctly, and I correctly found the `AvroKeyInputFormat` in the `org.apache.avro.mapreduce` package. So what am I missing here ?
I checked some `SO` post but I found no relevant answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Either create a far jar and add all your dependent jar in the fat jar.
2. Use cli -libjars to add the dependent jars in the distributed cache or Programmatically add the jars using Job.addLibPath().

Idea is to make all the jars available to the remote JVM invoked during MR.

Comment: thank you, I uploaded the `avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar` in the remote server, I added it with command `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar` and then launched again the job, and I get the exact same error

Comment: This is not the right Aprroach, In case you just want to make your job run add it to Java class path Please add it to CLASSPATH  so thats its visible to JVM.    Once the process is running can you please provide the output of ps -eaf with the id of your process which makes it easier to debug.

Comment: I tried to follow, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994644/hadoop-external-jars`. Could you tell me what is the command you have in mind ?

Comment: following the `java` documentation I tried to add `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar`, but I get the same problem

Comment: tried also `export LIBJARS=jar1.jar,jar2.jar` and hadoop jar myjar.jar input output -libjars ${LIBJARS} which also throws the same error.

Comment: @user247 your Avro jar isn't named  `jar1.jar,jar2.jar`

Comment: @cricket_007 my Avro dependency looks like : `avro-1.7.7.jar` and `avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar`. Sorry, I don't understand your point

Comment: @user247 You said you tried `export LIBJARS=jar1.jar,jar2.jar`... Verbatim, that's not correct... Besides that, a shaded jar is the correct way to get this working

Comment: @cricket_007, sorry I am not sure I am understanding, `jar1.jar,jar2.jar` stands for `avro-1.7.7.jar,avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar`, is that not correct ?

Comment: besides, when I run the `hadoop` command with `-libjars` set to `/hdfs/path/avro-1.7.7.jar,/hdfs/path/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar`, I get the same error

Comment: @cricket_007 in fact, I followed this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890087/problem-with-libjars-in-hadoop` with no success

Comment: @user247 That's only necessary if you did not make a shaded jar... It's not clear how you've compiled your project, and how you've sent it to the cluster

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not that familiar to `hadoop`, as for the project I used the `intellij` built-in artefact builder, and I downloaded the code I didn't find any `gradle` or `pom.xml` at the root of the app